# Concatenate a string within a text cell with other string at (the same place - delimiter) in other cells

Tags: excel, text, delimiter

First of all, just to be clear, I am using Excel 2013 so I won't be able to access the new fancy stuff on Excel 2016.

Second of all, I need help as I haven't been able to work out a solution or at least a method to my problem below.

I will try my best with the formatting. Perhaps a screenshot is better

[image: See example]
So for this question, I have 3 columns and lots of rows. 
The delimiter in each cell is **;** . There will be the same number of this delimiter in each cell on the same row.
But each row will have different numbers of delimiter.
There is an assumed value before the first, after the last and in between the delimiters.

I've been looking for a way to concatenate or join these value that in at the same place within these delimiters together into the same text but I couldn't think of anything.

So for example:

```
          Column 1 - Column 2 - Column 3
   Row 1   a;b;c      1;2;3      q;w;e   
   Row 2  
   Row 3
```

So I would for column 4 to contain the result of concatenating which is "a1q", column5 "b2w" and column 6 "c3e"

Or it could just be all in column 4 with a delimiter which is something like "a1q;b2w;c3e"

Same thing with row 2 and 3 but they may have more or fewer values. This is why I need something scale-able.

I don't think it is possible with normal Excel unless VBA is involved. I hope I made the question clear and thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53417802/edit) to give us a clear example of initial data and expected result? Also, what have you tried so far and how is it failing to achieve your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should put everything in Column 4 or "D".

```
Sub splitter()
    Dim SubBNameSplit() As String, BuildNameSplit() As String, NumberSplit() As String, result As String
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim x As Range
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For Each x In .Range("A2:A" & lrow)
                SubBNameSplit() = Split(.Range("A" & x.Row), ";")
                BuildNameSplit() = Split(.Range("B" & x.Row), ";")
                NumberSplit() = Split(.Range("C" & x.Row), ";")
                result = ""

                For i = LBound(SubBNameSplit) To UBound(SubBNameSplit)
                    result = result & SubBNameSplit(i) & BuildNameSplit(i) & NumberSplit(i) & ";"
                Next i

                .Range("D" & x.Row).Value = result
            Next x
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was what I had in mind, but I didn't know about the Split function or the LBound. (I am not that familiar with working with arrays).

I managed to edit the smaller loop i to format the concatenation to how I want.